# Flutter Firebase Google Auth doesn't work in production

Tags: firebase, flutter-web, social-authentication

I'm trying to get my Flutter Web app to work with Firebase Google Auth. Everything works locally, but on the production server (hosted on Firebase) I just get the following not helpful stack trace:

```
js_helper.dart:1111 Uncaught 
b @ js_helper.dart:1111
$0 @ async_patch.dart:710
auu @ schedule_microtask.dart:40
auO @ schedule_microtask.dart:49
$1 @ async_patch.dart:49
awf @ js_helper.dart:1807
(anonymous) @ js_helper.dart:1839
childList (async)
$1 @ async_patch.dart:62
ail @ async_patch.dart:27
a8H @ zone.dart:1495
ii @ zone.dart:1707
pJ @ future_impl.dart:665
el @ future_impl.dart:50
nS @ future_impl.dart:33
hN @ future_impl.dart:21
$1 @ google_sign_in_web.dart:111
ar8 @ js_helper.dart:836
afa @ core_patch.dart:84
atA @ js_patch.dart:542
(anonymous) @ js_patch.dart:520
e.Zn @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:231
gk @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:234
bk @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:234
_.Mj.Vt @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:233
Kj @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:226
Promise.then (async)
Fj @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:226
_.Jj @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:226
ck @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:233
Lj @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:232
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:227
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:352
$u.dispatchEvent @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:262
_.Wv.Pv @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:297
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:289
_.h.LY @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:284
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:286
```

This is a brand new project with the latest Flutter / Firebase dependencies. My index html looks like this:

```
...
<head>
   <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="myActualId.apps.googleusercontent.com">
</head>
<body>
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
```

I also added the domain I'm using in the Firebase console "Sign-in method" under "Authorised Domains". What can I do to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Firefox is better in terms of reporting this issue. In contrast to the Chrome console, Firefox console produced a nice error message (unfortunately I haven't copied the exact message), telling me that the client ID was not registered with Google Cloud Services. There must be a synchronization issue between Firebase Console (where the ID was registered) and Google Cloud Console (where the ID was not registered).